# Using Apache hudi library in java clients

Tags: apache-hudi

I am a hudi newbie. I was wondering if Hudi client libraries can be used straight from java clients to write to Amazon S3 folders. I am trying to build a system that can store a large no. of events upto 50k/second that will be emitted from a distributed system of over 10 components. I was wondering if I could build a simple client using a Hudi client library that buffers this data and then periodically just writes it into a Hudi datastore?

Comment: Hi. Hope this finds you well. Have you managed to write Hudi files on S3 using Java?